# bulkindexerror in python elasticsearch

Tags: python, http, elasticsearch

```
def submit_es_injection(self, data):
        if settings.SUBMIT_TO_ES:
            client = Elasticsearch(
                hosts=["localhost"],
                scheme="https",
                port="9200",
                use_ssl=False,
                verify_certs=False,
                http_auth=("elastic", "password"),
                timeout=60
            )

            for ok, result in helpers.streaming_bulk(
                    client=client,
                    actions=data,
                    chunk_size=10000
            ):
                action, result = result.popitem()
                doc_id = "/%s/" % (result["_id"])
                if not ok:
                    logger.error("Failed to %s document %s: %r" % (action, doc_id, result))
        else:
            for value in data:
                print(value)`
```

Hi guys, I receive a bulkindexError suggesting 10000 documents failed to index. Can someone guide me to fix the issue? thanks!`

Comment: Welcome to SO Tonio. What is the error message you get ? The post does now show what exception you are getting.